# Catching Node's 20 Second Request Timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver

If you create a default HTTP server in node.js, my understanding is each request needs to be handled within 20 seconds or it will be killed.

1. Is this option configurable, and if so, how?
2. Is it possible to catch the timeout and gracefully end the request (e.g., write a error 500 header and some helpful text out on the response)

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout